# YU Yureka stuck at Cyanogen logo

Tags: cyanogenmod, micromax-yu-yureka

My YU Yureka is stuck at the Cyanogen logo. I was just using Chrome with very low battery when it suddenly restarted and got at stuck at the Cyanogen logo. I don't have any backups.

I've been trying to start the phone in safe mode but none of the methods I've tried have been working.

Kindly suggest a way to start my mobile. If you can't help me I'll take it to a service center, would they be able to recover all data completely without any losses?

Kindly suggest solutions/sites/videos that may be helpful to me.

Device model: AO5510
Cyanogen OS version: 12.1
Android version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into TWRP if you have it installed, if you don't have TWRP installed on your device you can follow the instructions here:   https://twrp.me/yu/yuyureka.html

In TWRP you should be able to back up your data onto a computer. When your data is safe you could either go to a service center and see if they can fix your phone or you could try flashing a new ROM and see if that fixes the problem. You can find many tutorials on how to flash a ROM with TWRP online.

Cyanogen download can be found here:
https://cyanogenupdatetracker.com/downloads/

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking while editing my answer, I forgot that you can't access you settings. It seems like the only way is to use TWRP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the battery and don't charge it for one day. next day try to connect with the charger

else
just try to remove battery and keep away for
3 hour

I hope issue will be solved...

This is happened because the yureka does not works properly with usb

Sometimes this happens because of overheating or hardbrick or old device not able to handle load or any bug

Answer (score -1):

This problem is cased due to your recently installed application.
Can solve this problem through remove that app. 
first open your mobile in safe mode and then remove the app in settings -> app
Note: Open your mobile in safe mode by pressing the both Volume plus and minus button at a boot time.